# I am unable to add a key value pair in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the code

```
        $tasks = $project->getTasks();

        foreach ($tasks as $key => $task) {
            $task['position'] = $space->getPosition();
            $task['symbol'] = $space->getSymbol();
        }
```

logically 'position' and 'symbol' should be added in the array 'task'. They get added in fact, but only inside the loop. They disappear outside the loop. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP foreach loops operate `by value` (on a copy of the data) unless otherwise specified. There are two possible solutions

```
foreach ($tasks as $key => $task) {
  $tasks[$key]['position'] = $space->getPosition();
  $tasks[$key]['symbol'] = $space->getSymbol(); 
}
```

Alternatively,

```
foreach ($tasks as &$task) {
            $task['position'] = $space->getPosition();
            $task['symbol'] = $space->getSymbol();
        }
```

See documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Both methods are fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you use `foreach` you are getting a *copy* of the array values.  You need to use a *reference* in the `foreach`.

```
foreach ($tasks as $key => &$task) {
    $task['position'] = $space->getPosition();
    $task['symbol'] = $space->getSymbol();
}
```

Note the `&`, that tells PHP to use a reference inside the loop.

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be something like this?

```
    $tasks = $project->getTasks();

    foreach ($tasks as $key => $task) {
        $tasks[$key]['position'] = $space->getPosition();
        $tasks[$key]['symbol'] = $space->getSymbol();
    }
```